# Can I call a cross-domain SOAP-XML service using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, soap

I've done a lot of R&D but can't find the exact answer. Can any body tell me if it is possible to call a cross-domain SOAP-XML service using jQuery, or not?

If possible, some code samples would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a cross-domain SOAP request with jQuery providing that the server properly implements the [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) mechanism. This involves answering with the appropriate HTTP headers and handle preflighted requests (i.e. an OPTIONS request) properly.

You can find more details in the following post from MDN: [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). There are then plenty of other resources online on how to make the call using jQuery.